# How can I Initialize IList

Tags: c#, xaml

So my datagrid is populated with a Ilist

```
public IList SelectedItem2 { get; set; }
```

I have a double click action where I want to interact with the row value selected at index zero.

```
<telerik:RadGridView SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem2}" ItemsSource="{Binding AllQueries, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
    <telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewRow">
              <Setter Property="cal:Message.Attach" Value="[Event MouseDoubleClick] = [Open2()]"/>
        </Style>
    </telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

When I do double click on the row this error is produced.
error produced `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I'm Wondering how do i fix this error, normally in the ViewModel I would do something like

```
SelectedItem2 = new IList();
```

But there's no such thing :s

Within Open2

```
 Interaction i;
 IRecord vm;
 using (var ctx = DB.Get()) i = ctx.Interactions.Find(SelectedItem2.IndexOf(0))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot initialize an interface.  You need to create an object that implements that interface:

```
SelectedItem2 = new ArrayList();
```

Or

```
SelectedItem2 = new List(of object);
```

I'd prefer to use a type if all your values are the same type:

```
IList(Of string) SelectedItem2;
SelectedItem2 = new List(of string);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a class that *implements* `IList`, like `List<T>` (where `T` is the type of object the list can contain) or `ArrayList`

Comment: The only issue with this implementation is that T is ambiguous, it's not one object, the query comes with different columns and changes based on my actions.

Comment: If your collection comes from an external source, does _it_ implement `IList`?  The point is, you can't _create_ an instance of an interface, you need a concrete type.

Comment: I Tried the ArrayList Implementation and I put a breakpoint at where SelectedItem2 is used, SelectedItem2 Count = 0, I believe that means no value is being passed. Any Ideas on what needs to be changed?

Answer (score 1):

IList is an interface. You can't instantiate interfaces. Use a concrete implementation of `IList` (such as `SelectedItem2 = new List()`, not `IList`).

Answer (score 0):

Ilist is an interface u should use list to instantiate.

```
SelectedItem2 = new List();
```

Comment: This answer is a bit short. Your answer could be expanded, for instance, with an example how an instantiation would look like.

Comment: I just started posting in stack overflow. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Check this link out http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a30c4f18-eb14-4aa9-948f-701bb04b591e/list-initialization. You cannot initialise an interface. So you would do:

```
SelectedItem2 = new List();
```